# Rails is incorrectly sending redirect response as status 200

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

My controller is used for both HTML and JSON requests, and behaves differently for each. Normally with the JSON request it will just `render` a JSON response, but if a special parameter is sent from the client, the JSON handler should perform a redirect as well:

```rb
# PATCH/PUT /posts/1
# PATCH/PUT /posts/1.json
def update
  return unless current_user == @post.user
  respond_to do |format|
    if @post.update(post_params)
      format.html {
        puts "HTML"
        redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.'
      }
      format.json {
        puts "JS"
        if params[:redirect].to_s == "true"
          puts "REDIRECT"
          # ~~~~ THIS REDIRECT ISNT WORKING ~~~~
          redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.'
        else
          puts "NO REDIRECT"
          render json: @post
        end
      }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Through those `puts` statements I can verify that the request is coming in with `format.json` and `params[:redirect].to_s == "true"`.

But I can see something peculiar in the Rails console logs:

```
Started PUT "/posts/2" for ::1 at 2020-07-08 01:43:06 -0700
Processing by PostsController#update as JSON
... other log output ...
JS
REDIRECT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/posts/2
Completed 200 OK in 33ms (ActiveRecord: 13.4ms | Allocations: 18286)
```

Why is it using status code `200` after a redirect? And in the browser I can confirm that the response has code `200`.

The browser is *not* redirecting after making the AJAX submission. And I suspect it has to do with this incorrect status code.

I tried explicitly passing `status: 301` in the `redirect_to` call but it made no difference.

---

**Update** after writing out this question and thinking about it a little, I suppose it's probably easier to just manually do the redirect using the `success` handler the browser. But I'm still curious why this doesn't work.

Comment: Can you try executing put request from your terminal or postman? I just created a new Rails application and added your code, and it seems fine it is giving me this output in the terminal: 
JS
REDIRECT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/posts/1
Completed 302 Found in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 1.1ms | Allocations: 3268)

Comment: @NikolaMilutinovic yeah, it's giving 200 from CURL as well. I really have no idea what explains the discrepancy between my results and yours.

Comment: I am getting some turbolinks commands in the responde body, though. `Turbolinks.clearCache()
Turbolinks.visit("http://localhost:3000/posts/2", {"action":"replace"})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this Medium article](https://medium.com/@rcdexta/handling-ajax-redirects-in-rails-d78aed498682):

> Apparently there is no clean way to do ajax redirects in Rails. The
> recommended way to do that is to send a regular 200 OK status code
> along with some special parameter signaling the javascript side that
> it is a REDIRECT.

The author suggests to make it clear with this workaround:

> On the rails side, we create a helper that returns a response that has
> no content but just one header x_ajax_redirect_url and status code
> 302.

```rb
def ajax_redirect_to(url)
    head 302, x_ajax_redirect_url: url
end
```

> A global ajax handler on the javascript side will intercept all ajax
> calls across the application and redirect on seeing the appropriate
> header construct.

```js
$.ajaxSetup({
    statusCode: {
        302: function (response) {
            var redirect_url = response.getResponseHeader('X-Ajax-Redirect-Url');
            if (redirect_url != undefined) {
                window.location.pathname = redirect_url;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

This looks as the cleanest solution to me for now.